# How can I make the code add up the winnings to only show a total and not separate winnings?

Tags: php

I am making a p.php file for my website and I came to a problem. The code is to show the people who won the most money from the casino (SA:MP not real life !!) but in the database, the winnings are saved as separate, so they aren't added together to give a total. If this doesn't make sense, let's say I play at casino now and win $5.000.000, it will save in the database as I won $5.000.000, then I play again and I win another $5.000.000, in the database there's now 2 columns of $5.000.000, it doesn't add up and show it as $10.000.000. And I was wondering if someone can help me, how do I add together each of the winnings that a player had and make it show the total on the website?

This is the code that I have so far :

```
<div class="panel" style="padding: 10px">

<?php if(!isset(Config::$_url[1])) { 

$w = Config::$g_con->prepare("SELECT `Username`,`Cash`,`data` FROM `logspacanea` ORDER BY `Cash`");

$w->execute();

?>

<table class="table table-minimal">

    <thead>

        <tr>

    
            <th>USER</th>

            <th>Data</th>

            <th>Cash Winnings</th>

        </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php $id = 1;

    while($user = $w->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

        echo '

        <tr>

            <td>'.Config::formatName($user->Username).'</td>

            <td>'.$user->data.'</td>

            <td>'.$user->Cash.'</td>

        </tr>

        ';

        $id++;

    }

    ?>

    </tbody>

</table>

<?php } else { 

    

} ?>

</div>
```

On the picture below, that's how it looks on the webiste, all the cash winnings are separate, and I want them to be added together to only show a total

[How it currently looks on the website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUXLr.png)

Everything is in the details of the problem.

Comment: What have yo tried? If you want someone to fix your code for you, please hire them!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a table named "users" and another table named "rewards". So you can make a query like this to take top users reward.

```
select user_id, user_login, (select sum(reward_value) from `rewards` where reward_user = user_id) as total_reward from `users` order by total_reward desc limit 10
```

Notice that with lots of rows, it will be a heavy query, so consider creating a column like total_reward and update that when the user wins a new reward. So you will be able to use this column as a sort column.

---

Update based on "Honk der Hase" comment:

if you record all users and rewards data in one table, you can use the below query:

```
SELECT Username, sum(Cash) as SumCash FROM logspacanea GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: You should avoid subqueries, instead use GROUP BY

Comment: Also you should try and avoid things like total_reward as this can be unreliable.

Comment: @Honk der Hase, could you please rewrite the query with group by ?

Comment: @Nigel Ren, that's just a symbolic phrase to explain !

Comment: Having total columns can easily become outdated if the records are amended or deleted.

Comment: Yes, if any row removed, the result of all related queries will be changed. This is not related to the concept of this question.

Comment: `SELECT Username, sum(Cash) as SumCash FROM logspacanea GROUP BY Username` gives the sum of all Cash for every Username